# Как закрыть от пользователей и поисковиков URL на которые сайт направляет AJAX запросы? И надо ли это делать?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Т.е. речь идёт о URL которые носят технический характер, и которые показывать пользователю не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

от роботов в robots.txt:

```
Disalow:/your/ajax/url
```

От пользователя смысл данного действия ни как не оправдает его реализацию. Так как вы делаете request а браузер его отслеживает. 
Вывод:

1. От роботов стоит закрыть.
2. От юзеров не стоит даже заморачиваться

Comment: Добавлю, что robots.txt не закрывает страницу от индексации. Просто поисковые роботы не ходят по этим страницам. Вообще это делается для снижения нагрузки на сервер. А для закрытия от индексации нужно заголовок отправлять или тег мета вставлять. Как раз напомнили об этом!